# Where am I doing wrong!! D3-CSV

Tags: internet-explorer, csv, d3.js

I am trying to prepare a simple Bar chart using a csv file in D3 platform. I watched a video on youtube "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnDa-mT0RMA" and wrote exactly a same code. Using normal data without CSV its working absolutely fine. However, when I am trying to use a csv file as shown in the video.. its not working. IE showing blank white screen. Where am I doing wrong?

Code that I have written is:

[image: code]

CSV File Data:

```
Report, Total_Visits
acb 15
crs 13
hrs 12
```

Comment: Your CSV data does not look valid. `acb` and `15` are not separated by a comma for instance.

Comment: Also, your script is probably throwing errors because you haven't closed the `d3.csv()` call. You need a right brace and closing paren `})`

Answer (score 2):

CSV stands for Comma Separated Values. What that means is that you need to separate each data point using a comma.

Here is your data properly formatted as CSV:

```
Report,Total_Visits
acb,15
crs,13
hrs,12
```

Also for future reference when you receive a blank page you can usually use the developer tools in your web browser to see the specific error. In the Google Chrome browser you can use CTRL-SHIFT-I to open the developer tools console. In the top right side of this area that opens up you should see a little red symbol with a number. This specifies how many errors you have and what errors there are. You should be able to double click on it to be taken to the console to see the errors or you can click on the word console in the top left of the developer tools. Within the console you should be able to scroll and see all your errors.